# Swift convert to date from string in Parse user object

Tags: swift, date, parse-platform

This is not working for me. I have a value I'm getting from a database that's clearly a valid Date and I can print it out fine:

```
let datefromu = "\(PFUser.current()!.object(forKey:"original_date_route_started")!)"
print("I fetched \(datefromu)")
```

that prints: `I fetched 2017-08-10 15:50:43 +0000`.

I must add that if I look in the raw database it is written as so:
`2017-08-10T15:50:43.436Z`

so I think that output is already Parse's way of formatting the output from the date field?

Bottom line, when I want to populate a date variable I have (original_date_route_started: Date?) and convert that string to a date, I'm getting nil!:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
self.original_date_route_started = formatter.date(from: datefromu)
```

Comment: It seems that `datefromu` is already a `Date` and not a `String`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to write `formatter.string(from: datefromu)`?

Comment: @rmaddy you are right. But how can I set it to my date variable? Swift doesn't know its a date.

Comment: @DávidPásztor no. I need a date not a string. And I already tried converting to string and back today again but to no avail. same issue

Comment: Which variable do you mean? If you want `datefromu` to be a `Date`, use a cast since it is already a `Date` (at least I think it is based on the print output).

Comment: Use subclassing to avoid manual conversion of data types in Parse. If you have already set `original_date_route_started`'s type as a `Date` in the Schema (using the dashboard or the REST API), it will be converted to Date (swift) / NSDate (objc).

Comment: You are referring to `String` representations of `Date` objects. This: `2017-08-10T15:50:43.436Z` is not a `Date` object, this is just a `String` representation of a Date. If `datefromu` is already a `Date` object, you need a `String` to get it to display in the format you mentioned. `Date` objects represent absolute points in time, so you cannot "convert" them between formats. You can only convert their `String` representations to take different formats and `TimeZone`s.

Comment: To set the record straight, you should either debug the variable's type of use `print(type(of: PFUser.current()!["original_date_route_started"]!))`. If it's output is "Date", then there's no need for DateFormatter (as @rmaddy said on the 1st comment). Why are you enclosing the Date in a String to begin with ?

Comment: well @nathan, I'm just trying to set my date variable to it. I tried casting toit but its not working

Comment: @rmaddy I am trying your route. Let me back up and work first with a definite string. I think I'm casting correctly but still getting nil. (This has nothing to do withParse anymore)
let datefromu = "2017-08-10-11:50:43"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
                        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
                        self.original_date_route_started = formatter.date(from: datefromu) as Date!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to convert `PFUser.current()!.object(forKey:"original_date_route_started")` to a Date ? Then you should consider subclassing to avoid dealing with DateFormatters:

Assuming `original_date_route_started` is correctly defined as a `Date` in Parse (if not, I'll update the answer):

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class UserParse: PFUser {

    @NSManaged var original_date_route_started: Date?

}
```

If you want to set a new value to it:

```
var user = UserParse.current()!
user.original_date_route_started = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -3600 * 4) // 4hs ago
user.saveInBackground()

// Your sample code:
let datefromu = UserParse.current()!.original_date_route_started
self.original_date_route_started = datefromu
```

---

Are you just having problems setting `self.original_date_route_started`'s value in another class that's not `PFUser` ? There are 2 ways to do it:

- `ISO8601DateFormatter` for [iOS >= 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter) (See [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/ISO8601DateFormatter.swift) for more details)

  ```
  let isoDateFormatter= ISO8601DateFormatter()
  ```
- Custom `DateFormatter` for [iOS >= 2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

  ```
  var isoDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
      $0.locale     = Locale(identifier:"en_US_POSIX")
      $0.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
      $0.timeZone   = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) // Or Locale(identifier: "GMT")
      return $0
  }(DateFormatter())
  ```

Converting string to date:

```
let testString = "2017-08-10T17:53:51+0000"
isoDateFormatter.date(from: testString)
```

Comment: I'm using original_date_route_started as a date value in many areas in my class, not necessarily within the scope of the Parse user. So I have it way up on top and keep referring to it as self.original_date_route_started

It is only when I don't have value for it , then I retrieve it from the Parse User in db, and am currently unsuccessfully trying to set it from that value

Comment: yes and in your example,  can you then set a variable that should be of type Date as so: self.original_date_route_started  = isoDateFormatter.date(from: testString)   I don't think so!   - this is all I'm trying to do!

Comment: What do you mean with *I don't think so!* ? That's the API: `func date(from string: String) -> Date?`. Your `DateFormatter` was set up incorrectly, please use the code above (you forgot to setup the Locale / TZ and the format string is incorrect). Working example: https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/598ca26ade80147f1a9d22f0

Comment: Thanks for the sample. let me check that out